# Как в переменную добавить значение

Tags: python

Как добавить значение из ввода input, в переменную token?

```
from SimpleQIWI import *
token = ""
phone = ""
api = QApi(token=token, phone=phone)
print('''
1.Проверка баланса.
2.Перевод средств.''')
a= int(input('Какое действие выполнить?:'))
if a == 1:
    print(api.balance)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поместите эту строку `api = QApi(token=token, phone=phone)` после считывания всех данных.

---

Попробуйте так:

```
from SimpleQIWI import *
token = input('Введите токен: ')
phone = input('Введите номер: ')
api = QApi(token=token, phone=phone)
print('''
1.Проверка баланса.
2.Перевод средств.''')

item = int(input('Какое действие выполнить?:'))
if item == 1:
    print(api.balance)
```

Comment: Дело в том, что я использую библиотеку SimpleQiwi, и мне необходимо вывести баланс. Вот полный код

Comment: @0x00 Добавьте этот код в сам вопрос.

Comment: Изменил код, проверяйте.

Comment: @0x00, Изменил ответ.